# Simple tool to monitor a Tomcat server using JMX

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jmx

I am a computer science student currently doing an internship. My boss has asked me to write a simple tool to monitor a Tomcat server. I am just starting this project so I'm basically just playing around to see how things work. I would like to create a simple jsp page that displays the results of some basic JMX queries. I am using the Eclipse IDE. Can someone give me some tips to get started?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a research assistant: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/152851

Comment: Is this a real use app, or just a test to see how good you are? In case, it's not a test, show JConsole to  your boss ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely don't have to re-invent the wheel, here. You can start with `jconsole`, which ships with your JDK: just run `jconsole [pid]` and `jconsole` will connect to the (locally) running process and let you observe everything via JMX.

If you want remote access to JMX-exposed information, you can use Tomcat's `manager` webapp along with the included `jmxproxy` servlet which allows you to remotely perform simple queries to get (and set) JMX properties.

There are other more fully-featured projects such as Jolokia ( http://www.jolokia.org/) that do similar kinds of things.

Assuming that you are using something like Nagios to automatically observe your Tomcat instance, something you definitely don't want to do it spin-up a JVM and make a remote (or even local) JMX connection to inspect a single JMX property (and then do that 5 times to observe 5 different properties, then do those 5 samples every 5 minutes, or 1 minute, or whatever). Instead, you probably want to use a proxy like one described above.

We've had great success coupling Nagios with the Tomcat manager's `jmxproxy` servlet. It will likely meet your needs for quite a while.

Comment: The OP mentions that he is trying to create a JSP page to display JMX output.  `jconsole` can't do that and the `jmxproxy` only displays local JMX information, not remote if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Comment: @Gray I mentioned jconsole because it is fairly full-featured. If the OP wants to write a "simple" JSP (ha ha) he's in for a surprise as now non-simple that task will be. `jmxproxy` runs inside Tomcat and provides an HTTP interface to JMX. So, you can remotely query JMX properties that are then locally-acquired.

Comment: Oh there's no question about the non-simple-ness of the task dude.  :-)

Comment: I appreciate your responses. I've played around a bit and see this is not going to be something I can just whip up...I'm totally upfront about the fact that I'm just fumbling around and doing the best I can. Basically I am tasked with writing a "Healthcheck" program that will monitor some programs running on Tomcat server. What specific challenges do you feel make this task "non-simple"?

Comment: I realize that probably the best way to go about this is to start with an existing tool, like Jolokia, which I've played around with a bit. However, I'd also like to at least write a "simple" application from scratch that can successfully return the result of a JMX query. Any tips on getting started with this?

Comment: You could look at the source code for Tomcat's `jxmproxy` servlet which is fairly straightforward: it takes a request parameter and turns it into a JMX query and then dumps the result to the response's output stream. That sounds like exactly what you want to do already.

Comment: That's an excellent idea. Where do I find the source for JMXProxy? I don't see it under webapps/manager/jmxproxy, which is where I'd expect to find it.

Comment: You can either download the Tomcat source from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi and look for `JMXProxyServlet.java` or browse the source online starting here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/. You want to look under the `java` directory in the `org.apache.catalina.manager` package.

Comment: @Phaedrus Sure. Let me clean it up a bit and I'll post it to the Tomcat wiki.

Comment: Much Appreciated - I have been monitoring collectionTime, collectionCount, but these 2 numbers just seem to increase and incrase.   Which value should I be looking at to get GC performance points ?

Comment: @Phaedrus I'm no GC expert. I recommend asking a new question on SF or even an OT question over on the Tomcat users' list.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of programmatically using JMX, there are a number of client classes out there.  Here's my [SimpleJMX project](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/).  With it you can use the `JmxClient` object to connect to and interrogate remote JVMs:

```
JmxClient client = new JmxClient("remote.sever.name", remotePortNumber);
Set<ObjectName> objectNameSet = client.getBeanNames();
...
```

Here are the [javadocs for JmxClient](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/javadoc/simplejmx/com/j256/simplejmx/client/JmxClient.html).