# Can Someone Help Me Understand Tomcat MBeans?

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, jmx, mbeans

A while back I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057213/simple-tool-to-monitor-a-tomcat-server-using-jmx) about monitoring a Tomcat server. Since that time I've played around a little bit and come up with a program that outputs a bunch of JMX information (MBeanServer names, MBean names, MBean attributes, their descriptions and values...) to a text file. This has been a great learning experience, but I'm having trouble wading through the considerable amount of information that I've generated to decide what is actually useful information to determine the health of the Tomcat server and the applications deployed on it. Can someone tell me what Tomcat MBean attributes describe a) the overall health of the Tomcat server and, b) the health of the webapps deployed on said server.

Comment: Sorry, but SO isn't really a tutorial site.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Jim. I reviewed the links you pointed me towards, and don't really see where the problem lies. My question is about a specific software tool commonly used by programmers and also meets the requirements set forth in the "How to Ask" guide.

Comment: Dan, it's mostly that your question is open-ended, and doesn't have a concrete 'right' answer. Your question right now seems to be boiled down to 'there's too much info out there.'. There isn't a *specific question* that can be answered. As written, this likely will devolve into a discussion. If the question could be rewritten as "Here's a sample TomCat JMX info text file. What are each of the parts within, and how can they be used to debug/troubleshoot performance problems?"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how my question is open-ended. I did not ask, "What are your favorite Tomcat MBeans?" or say "Someone please tell me about Tomcat, MBeans and the JMX protocol." My question is as follows: What Tomcat MBean attributes describe a) the overall health of the Tomcat server and, b) the health of the webapps deployed on said server. I do not think that posting the JMX info text file would be useful...it is quite long. I will edit my initial post to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I found out. All of the information I was getting initially was coming strictly from Tomcat MBeans. This information was useful to a point, but what I failed to realize was that there were other sorts of MBeans out there. I was able to uncover a lot of useful information by looking at RuntimeMXBeans, ThreadMXBeans and MemoryMXBeans.