# Tomcat debugging not possible through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I've made a script called `debug.sh` and placed it under the bin directory (start it with `./debug.sh`) to start Tomcat 8 in debugging mode:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
bash catalina.sh jpda start
```

But if it started, there is now message which says, that Tomcat is listening on port 8000. Also if I type

```
netstat -nat
```

there is no application listening on port 8000.

What exact configuration do I have to set, to remote debug my Tomcat 8 server which is running on a specific IP or do I have just a little problem in my script?

Comment: Eclipse does not support remote control of Tomcat yet.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer has been updated following the comments, I did not understand the problem in the first place.*

I guess you have followed [that doc](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing): this is about developing Tomcat itself.

I am not sure you are using the proper way to configure the port (I don't know your specific configuration details). In a standard environment, the ports are configured in the [server.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/server.html) (note that several different ports are used by Tomcat for the different services).

To remotely monitor your server, you should use a JMX client. As far as I know, Eclipse doesn't include one (or at least not one documented) - you could code one as this is a [Java specification (JSR262)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=262). You have one in a standard Java environement ([JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)). By default, JMX is not enabled on Tomcat. If you need to enable it, the fine way is to [follow the doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html).

Tomcat JMX monitoring and JConsole are both available in most versions of Tomcat and the Java runtime.

The [following exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057213/simple-tool-to-monitor-a-tomcat-server-using-jmx) seems to be about your problem.

Comment: The tomcat server is running on a different machine and I can only access the server via console. The server system is Ubuntu and the system where I want to debug from is Windows 7. So the parameters have to be set on the Ubuntu server while starting Tomcat.

Comment: OK, I did not understand properly your situation in the first place. I thought this was an Eclipse problem (because of the Eclipse tag). Because the comment is discouraged, I am going to modify my answer.

Comment: So http://blogs.mulesoft.org/debugging-your-tomcat-webapp-with-eclipse/ is not working with a Tomcat server running on another machine?

Comment: Well, to be honest I have no idea of that specific use of the debugging feature, but Jason Britain is a reliable source. Perhaps your specific problem is the set JPDA_ADDRESS which sets a local variable... Using an export instead of set would make the variable available to the environment. Please tell me if debugging that way works...